# Pandas: How to sort dataframe on columns with same column labels

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck with a dataframe that has non-unique column labels, and I need to sort it. However I'm not able to because the columns are non-unique. My intuition says instead of sorting by the column name, I can sort by the column position. However, even with this approach I'm getting `ValueError: The column label 'Region' is not unique.`

Here's my code sample, I was having a hard time recreating a df with non-unique column labels so bear with me:

```
data_dict = {'Region': {0: 'Peninsula',
  1: 'Portland',
  2: 'San Francisco',
  3: 'Los Angeles',
  4: 'San Francisco'},
 'Region Num': {0: 2.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 4.0, 3: 3.0, 4: 1.0}}

df_test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)

df_test.rename(columns={'Region Num':'Region'}, inplace=True)

df_test.sort_values(by=[df_test.columns[0],df_for_excel.columns[1]], ascending=(False,False), inplace=True)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create temporary helper columns copying the 2 columns by position using `iloc`, sort by the temporary helper columns.  Finally, drop the temporary helper columns, as follows:

```
df_test = df_test.assign(A=df_test.iloc[:, 0], B=df_test.iloc[:, 1]).sort_values(by=['A', 'B'], ascending=(False,False)).drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_test)


          Region  Region
2  San Francisco     4.0
4  San Francisco     1.0
1       Portland     1.0
0      Peninsula     2.0
3    Los Angeles     3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Right: PANDAS allows you to index columns by position, but that simply maps to the attribute (column) name.  To sort on a column, you must have a unique name.

In this case, you'll need to rename all of the columns, just to change the duplicate(s).  Then you can sort.

Comment: Once you've changed the column names to be unique, simply sort by columns as you were doing before.  You can use either name or index.